# How to add application keys in WPF?

Tags: wpf, properties

I am very new to WPF and I am from the xamarin.foms. I am trying for the login functionality for the WPF application. Here, when the user login the application I need to save the user details in the application kyes like in xamarin.forms.

```
Application.Current.Properties["UserEmailId"] = userDetails.UserName;
```

so that, for next login no need to take values from user. How to do this in WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with [User Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/using-application-settings-and-user-settings):

```
Properties.Settings.Default.UserName = userDetails.UserName;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Comment: Thanks, @pinki, I have created new settings file as UsersSettings and added that file to properties folder. When  I run the application the second time, the values are null.

Comment: On initial login: Properties.UserSettings.Default.UserName =userDetails.UserName;
               Properties.UserSettings.Default.Save();
Second time login: Properties.UserSettings.Default.UserName is giving null instead of previously saved value.

Comment: Did you set your username setting's scope as user?

Comment: Thank you soo much @pinki, I did not set the username setting's scope, this is the reason for getting null. You saved my day :-)